# Convert a PictureBox inside an listBox back into a PictureBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, listbox, picturebox

i have some PictureBoxes in my program with different colors and I want to count, how much boxes there are for one color. So I created a function to count it:

```
private void cmdCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counterWhite, counterRed, counterGreen, counterYellow, counterBlue, counterOrange = 0;

        if (alreadyAdded == false)
        {
            lstBox.Items.Add(picA1);
            lstBox.Items.Add(picA2);
            lstBox.Items.Add(picA3);
            //...

            alreadyAdded = true;
        }

        //Log
        String value = Convert.ToString(lstBox.Items.Count);
        lblLog.Text = "Objects in array: " + value;

        for(int i = 0; i < lstBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(lstBox.Items[i].BackColor == Color.White)
            {
                counterWhite += 1;
            }
            else if...


        }
    }
```

I know, that my for-loop will not work that way, but it's the basic idea how I want to do it. 
I have put all my PictureBoxes into my list and in the for-loop I want to count them. First it should play as long as the list is long, then every time it goes to the next box and should check the color of it and then add a one to the seperate counters. The problem is that I get errors every time and I have no idea how to read out the values of the BackColors in my list for each item.

Thank you for maybe helping me out :)

Comment: I think a `foreach` would make more sense here. `foreach(Picturebox pBox in lstBox)` and then `pBox.BackColor`. Don't see a problem either.

Comment: It says there is no definition for "BackColor" for the type 'object'. I know that this is true, above it's an idea how to do it, but my question is how to read out the BackColor of the objects in my list and it was a try to get it with "lstBox.Items[i].BackColor == Color.White" but it doesn't work. So how can I read it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because the `ListBox.Items` collection is an ObjectCollection... it has to be, since it allows you store any object you want in it.

You'll have to cast the object back to a `PictureBox` before accessing properties on it:

```
if (((PictureBox)lstBox.Items[i]).BackColor == Color.White)
{
    counterWhite += 1;
}
```

Or you could switch to a `foreach` loop and cast them all at once (using LINQ):

```
foreach (var pBox in new lstBox.Items.Cast<PictureBox>())
{
    if (pBox.BackColor == Color.White)
    {
        counterWhite += 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Don't use a `ListBox` control as temporary storage for referencing your `PictureBox` controls though. You could create a `List<PictureBox>` to store references in, and then you won't have to cast when you iterate through the collection.

Or better yet (and the one I'd choose), just query the controls on your Form and count the number of controls of type "PictureBox" that have the BackColor you're looking for (using LINQ again).

```
var counterWhite = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                           .Count(p => p.BackColor == Color.White);

var counterGreen = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                           .Count(p => p.BackColor == Color.Green);
```